# Create Visual Studio Setup Project using self-contained deployment mode for .NET 5

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, .net-5, setup-project

I'm trying to create a setup project for a WPF application (.NET 5) using VS Community 2019. I've installed the extension for the setup project and I'm following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2019). Since I want to deploy in a self-contained manner I've created a publishing profile and used its relative path for the Publish Items => PublishProfilePath entry in the setup project. However when I try to build I get the following error:

"Could not find the publishing profile ... used in project output group 'Publish Items from ... (Active)"

So is it at all possible to build a self-contained setup project? Also it's confusing that VS says that the "PublishProfilePath" is only used for .NET Core 3 projects whereas the guide mentioned above seems to indicate that it can be used for .NET Core 3 and above.

Any suggestions on this are highly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding a screenshot of the error. [Check out the Q&A area in the installer below.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects&ssr=false#qna)

Comment: When trying to provide the screenshot you've asked for I've found the solution below. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The mistake I made was using the wrong path (the "Target location" from the publishing profile):

[image: target location]

So the correct way to do this is as follows:

1. Create a publish profile which is automatically named like this:
   [image: FolderProfile.pubxml]
2. Make the following entry in "PublishProfilePath" (don't forget to prepend "Properties\PublishProfiles"):
   [image: PublishProfilePath entry]

Then it is possible to build a self-contained installer.

Comment: Hi wosi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See can I answer my own question.., Just a reminder :)

Comment: I expected the installer project to execute the publish profile, but it doesn't. Why do we specify the pubxml file then? Is it really required to have a pre-build event do the publishing?